# How to compare strings in if condtion in python?

Tags: python

I have two text files

1) foo.txt

2) write.txt

foo.txt contains

```
welcome
```

and write.txt is blank text file.

```
fo = open("foo.txt", "r+")
str = fo.readlines();
fo1 = open("write.txt", "wb")
print str[0]


if (str[0] == "welcome" ): fo1.write( "hoola");

fo.close()

fo1.close()
```

The above lines are the python code.
When I run it there are no errors.

The output is

```
welcome
```

Text files after running the program:

1) foo.txt

```
welcome
```

2) write.txt is completely blank

so the test "hoola" is not written on the file write.txt

With the output, i made sure that str[0] is 'welcome' but the text is not written to the 2nd text file
How can i correct this code to compare the first element of str[] with the string 'welcome'

Comment: are you sure that there is no `newline` char at the end of the *welcome* string? The code you wrote works for me

Comment: Why do you open file for writing in [binary mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) ?
 Also first file you just read... Try 'r' and 'w' instead

Comment: Yeah it worked, it was a missing of newline char , Thanks a lot

Comment: Why are you `fo1 = open("write.txt", "wb")` and not `fo1 = open("write.txt", "w")`? Besides this, I wouldn't use `str` as a variable's name...

Comment: I corrected as all you said, and now it working , Thanks a lot to all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `open('foo.txt').readlines()` will give you the list `['welcome\n']`, you are missing the newline character in your check. So either check your string against `'welcome\n'` or strip the line you have read in of any newline characters (and whitespace) with the `str.strip` method.

In addition, don't use the variable name `str`, you will mask the builtin `str` type.

Comment: This is not true. The output of my `open('foo.txt').readlines()` is `['welcome']` without the `\n`

Comment: @Francesco well apparently I guessed right that OP's file ends with a newline character, or OP would not have accepted this answer.

Comment: From what you wrote it seems that `readlines()` adds a new line. I reccomend you to edit your answer as it is misleading

Comment: @Francesco I don't think it seems like that. In OP's case, the call to `readlines` returns `['welcome\n']`. I did not mean to give a general lecture on the `readlnes` function, because it is out of scope for this trivial question.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you can do:

-If there is any trailing whitespace it can mess up the string match and can be removed with:

```
import string
clean_input = string.rstrip(str[0])
if clean_input == 'welcome': ...
```

-Also you could use regular expressions to pattern match if you only care about the first characters matching. My personal experience is that this is a more reliable way to do text parsing:

```
import re
if re.match('welcome', str[0]): ...
```